# QDataWidgetMapper and QDateEdit values

Tags: c++, qt, qtsql, qsqltablemodel, qdatetime

I have QSqlTableModel with some table, let's suppose that it's a

```
model->setTable("Person");
```

And also I have QDataWidgetMapper which mapps some widgets (lineedits etc.) to appropriate columns in model.
So the problem is in `QDateEdit` element.

```
mapper->addMapping(birthEdit, Person_Birthdate);
```

When I change the date in `birthEdit` (`QDateEdit`) the values isn't actually changed in appropriate table because they are stored in a different format, and I also get an error:

```
"QODBCResult::exec: unable to bind variable: "[Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver]...".
```

The date in database is stored in **"yyyy-MM-dd"** while the `QDateEdit` returns the date in another (I suppose). As far as I know `QDataWidgetMapper` uses USER property in mapped widget to get/set the value.

How can I solve my problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two approaches to be taken as per the [following page](http://qtwiki.remdex.info/How_to_map_QDataWidgetMapper_and_QDateEdit_%3F):

- Subclass QSqlRelationalDelegate and make appropriate changes in setEditorData and setModelData methods.
- Extend QDateEdit and make it handle timestamp data and convert to QDate object.

Comment: The [following page](http://qtwiki.remdex.info/How_to_map_QDataWidgetMapper_and_QDateEdit,_QDateTimeEdit_?) is empty and there no information at all.
I tried the first way - subclass QSqlRelationaDelegate etc. and it helped, thanks.
Can you please explain what do you mean "Extend QDateEdit and make it handle timestamp data and convert to QDate object"?

Comment: @ScienceSE: ah, you are right. There was some copy/paste mistake on my side, hehe. It is fixed now, and you can also get more explanation over there about the second solution.

Comment: Thanks. But I think that the example in article is incomplete because of NOTIFY dateChanged signal which author forgot to add into his class :) Anyway I've understood the general idea.